# Which Macs are compatible with macOS Sierra?

Tags: compatibility, macos

Is there a list of officially-supported Mac models on to which macOS Sierra can be installed?

I presume it is the same as OS X El Capitan as there does not appear to be many changes which would warrant removing some models of Mac from the supported list, but I can't seem to be able to confirm this.

Comment: If your Mac is not officially supported, please [tell Apple through their feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html) page. This feedback can make a difference!

Comment: @GrahamMiln Yes! 2009 MacBook Pro owners unite!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [Keynote announced the following supported hardware](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Td4dA.jpg):

- Late 2009: MacBook (MacBook6,1)
- Late 2009: iMac (21.5" iMac10,1, 27" iMac10,1 and iMac 10,2)
- Mid 2010: MacBook Pro (13" MacBookPro7,1, 15" MacBookPro6,2, 17" MacBookPro6,1)
- Mid 2010: Mac mini (Macmini4,1)
- Mid 2010 : Mac Pro (MacPro5,1)
- Late 2010: MacBook Air (11" MacBookAir3,1, 13" MacBookAir3,2)

**All later models are unquestionably compatible.** A public list (on [Apple's website](http://www.apple.com/macos/sierra-preview/)) is ***not*** available yet, but a list may be available in the [Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/download/) (Developer Only).

**For the Developer Preview:** Registered Developers can access `InstallableMachines.plist` in `InstallESD.dmg` for a full list of officially supported Mac board-ids.

It may be possible to install on some unsupported hardware through [modifying firmware](https://twitter.com/tapbot_paul/status/742488369783922688), [the installer](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/macos-10-12-sierra-unsupported-macs-thread.1977128/), or other methods.

Comment: In reference to "_However, these do not appear to be a firm list_"... There always seems to be a difference between what's officially supported and what can it actually run on in cases such as this. Of course it's in Apple's interest to obsolete hardware to coax users to buy a new Mac along with the new OS. :)

Comment: I am able to install macOS Sierra on VMWare Fusion. The developer preview installer is not enforcing the officially supported hardware. The restriction appears to be imposed by the Mac App Store application when downloading.

Comment: @GrahamMiln you sure about that? It refuses to even start on my Late 2008 MacBook Pro.

Comment: @NetherLinks, When you say "_It refuses to even start_", in what context are your referring... Starting the installer from within a running OS X or from a USB Installer created from the downloaded installer?

Comment: @user3439894 Within OS X states "This version ... cannot be installed on this computer". A `createinstallmedia` USB shows Prohibitory symbol.

Comment: With VMWare Fusion 8, create an OS X 10.11 machine and launch the macOS Sierra installer from within this virtual machine. Trying to create a brand new virtual machine from a developer preview rarely works.

Comment: @GrahamMiln I'm well aware virtual machines work. I was trying to say that trying to install on unsupported hardware may throw errors (without modifying the installer). I apologize if my wording was poor.

Comment: Do you have information on which new features require a newer Mac only? (E.g., would universal clipboard function on a 2011 MacBook Pro?)

Comment: @kal-al Not at the moment.